# How to delete part of a CSV string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
"116,118,120,130"
```

and will want to delete either the first, last or any value in between upon execution.

To to this I was using:

```
"116,118,120,130".gsub('118','')
```

but the problem is the string contains an extra unnessesary comma:

```
"116,,120,130"
```

and if I use

```
"116,118,120,130".gsub(',116','')
```

it will remove the comma, but then won't match "116" in the string as there is no comma in front of "116"

How can I match parts of my string that may or my not have the comma in front of value I am removing elegantly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, I might try something like...

```
"116,118,120,130".split(',').reject{|e|e=="116"}.join(',')
```

Comment: +1 This is probably the easiest way to do it.  Split the string into an array (breaking at the commas), then remove whatever you don't want, then re-assemble the array into a comma-delineated string.  While it's probably possible to do the same with `gsub` or similar, this method seems much less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two easy ways to do this.  First, you can use a regular expression.  A simple one like:

```
"116,118,120,130".gsub(/(,118)|(118,)/,'')
```

Will do what you want.  With 118 replaced by whatever value you are looking for. But if you are looking for more then 1 value, why not just split and recombine it. For example

```
"116,118,120,130".split(',').reject {|val| val == '118' || val == '130'}.join(',')
```

Returns "116,120"

Answer (score 0):

If it's slightly more complicated CSV data (e.g. it has embedded commas), use the [csv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) standard library module

```
require 'csv'
str = 'abc,def,"ghi,jlk",mno'
fields = CSV.parse_line(str)
fields.reverse!  # or do whatever manipulation
new_line = CSV.generate_line(fields) 
# => "mno,\"ghi,jlk\",def,abc\n"
```